# Cannot access static files through certain routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

My routes are configured in app.js. The /users route works as expected except when rendering express layouts I cannot access the css files located at ./css/style.css

If I open a page using the /users route, I can see it's looking for /users/css/style.css but I thought setting the directory to static would override this?

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use(express.static('css'));
```

Comment: move `express.static` call before your route handlers

Comment: that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Added this to my app.js file:

```
// GET /static/style.css etc.
app.use('/users', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

More information here if needed: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what `app.use(express.static('css'));` does is to **serve statically the files starting from the given path**, in this case `css`.

A good practice is to create a folder called `public` and use it to serve it's inner files statically. So your static folder should be like this:

```
-public
  -css
    -style.css
```

and your app.js should have `app.use(express.static('./public'));`

Now, another problem you may be having is the way you cast the paths (url) to load certain files.

Let's say you request `http://localhost:PORT/users` and the served HTML loads a stylesheet using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH">`.

You could write the **PATH** in 2 ways.

- `css/style.css`
- `/css/style.css`

The difference is that the first method will search for the file **relative to the path you're already in** (e.g `http://localhost:PORT/users/css/style.css`). The other method will get such file using the 'domain' you are already in as a starting point (e.g `http://localhost:PORT/css/style.css`.

Hope this helps c: